# In Which assembly the Interface or Abstraction resides?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

In Dependency Injection, Let's say I have a **Consumer** in **AssemblyA** and the **Dependency implementation** in **AssemblyB**. I am using **Constructor Injection** so that the Abstraction of the Dependency will be passed as a constructor argument to the Consumer. In which assembly does the abstraction reside? AssemblyA or AssemblyB or Some other assembly (**AssemblyC**) So that AssemblyA and AssemblyB can refer the Abstraction from AssemblyC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is called Dependency Inversion and is one of the SOLID principles. Dependency inversion says that you should depend on abstractions and not implementations. It also states that lower layers should not be aware of higher layers.

With that in mind everything is crystal clear =)

```
IUserService // abstraction, where should this be placed?
DbUserService //implementation, placed in YourApp.Core
UserController(IUserService) // usage, placed in YourApp.UI
```

Well. Since lower layers (Core) should not be aware of higher layers (UI) we can't place the interface in the UI project.

So we got two choices: A third assembly or the Core assembly.

There is also another principle called "[Separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html)" which states that the interfaces should be placed in another package/assembly.

I usually place the interface in the same package as the implementation to keep it simple.

Comment: Separated Interface is especially useful in bigger projects. It allows you to lower compile time, enables parallel development, and enforces architectural boundaries. It can be overkill for smaller projects.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you have;

```
class AssemblyA.ClassA
{
    public ClassA(ClassB arg) { ... }
}

abstract class AssemblyB.ClassB
{ }

class AssemblyC.ClassC : AssemblyB.ClassB // some concrete implementation of ClassB
{  }
```

Then;

- ClassB can belong to either AssemblyA, or AssemblyB - in this case, AssemblyA references AssemblyB
- ClassC can belong to either AssemblyA, AssemblyB, or AssemblyC - in this case, AssemblyA references **both** AssemblyB and AssemblyC, and AssemblyC references AssemblyB

This is a trivialisation of your question.

Comment: Yes you made my question easily understandable by giving a code snippet of my intention. Actually I don't want to drag AssebmlyX when i unit test AssemblyA. So I am just wondering if it is ok to keep the abstractions in a seperate Assembly.

Comment: Yes, if ClassA has no direct knowledge of ClassC, through use of interfaces then that is great. Less coupling is a good thing, and it will make unit testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Abstractions (including interfaces) belong to the caller

### Longer answer

Checkout the [implementations section of the DI wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

This shows two implementations:

- Abstractions belong to the higher level component
- Abstractions are in their own package

To understand this, it's important to understand what the abstraction is trying to do in Dependency Inversion. The goal is for the higher-level flow to define dependencies on it's own terms, but let someone else provide implementations later. This allows the high-level flow to avoid changes when low-level implementations change and to flexibly swap different implementations.

If the interface is coupled to the implementation, then we don't achieve this goal because the interface is [not an abstraction](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/). The interface will change with the implementation and the higher-level flow is not insulated from change.

Also consider the package dependency structure. If the interface belongs with the implementation, then the high-level flow must reference the low-level package for any use case. However, if the abstraction belongs to the high-level flow, then we can reference different implementations based on different use cases. This is the basis architectures like [Ports and Adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) and [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). I think Mark Seeman [describes it well](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same/)